# Spotify: Linking tracks on page

Tags: spotify

How can I link different tracks present in a particular tab on spotify page, so that when clicked on spotify next/previous button the next/previous track is played.
 Presenlty it is not playing anything if clicked on next button, when it should be starting to play the next track present on the page 
My script looks like this,

```
 $.each(allTracks,function(index,track){         
       models.Track.fromURI(track, function(track) {
       models.Album.fromURI(track.album.uri, function(album) {                      
          var single_track = models.Track.fromURI(track.uri);
          var single_track_playlist = new models.Playlist();
          single_track_playlist.add(single_track);                
          var pl = new views.Player();
          pl.context = single_track_playlist;
          if(index==0) {       
            $("#firstTrack").append(pl.node);
          }
         .............
         .............
```

Can anyone please guide me on how I should be going around doing this?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the context of each `Player` view is a playlist with that single track. If you want to render your tracks as players, and have them synchronized so that the next track plays after the one before ends, you need to create a custom solution.

You can check this [Grid Play Spotify App](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-grid-play), that shows an example of how to achieve it. It basically creates custom `Player` views that respond to certain events triggered by the `Player` model and other `Player` views.

Comment: Your Grid Play Spotify App helped me with my problem. Thank you for your help, JMPerez